# Blending 3 layers in OpenGL with background

Tags: c++, opengl, blending

What would be glBlendfunc() parameters for achieving the following effect:

0) background, non-transparent.

1) first_layer, just one color.

2) semi-transparent sphere, that blends with first_layer but not with background...

**EDIT**

Below are the renderings that I hope show what I am trying to achieve.

[image: This is the original - sphere over background]

[image: This is the desired effect - green color between sphere and background and sphere is blended with color but not background]

Comment: "semi-transparent sphere, that blends with first_layer but not with background..." What does this mean? Can you show a mockup image?

Comment: yes I will make and post it in a couple hours. Thank you!

Comment: Added the renderings to the question

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand why you want to mess with transparency. Can't you just change the color of the sphere when you draw it? Otherwise just draw the circle of color without blending, and then draw sphere with (src, 1-src) as described below. I feel like I'm missing something though.

Comment: I just tried to simplify things for the sake of example, the case is a bit more complicated - in real situation instead of a sphere I have a rendering of fur (lots of triangles) using blending helps to get to a compromise between performance and looks (using shaders and lighting decreases the performance). I indeed can draw the object (fur) twice, but that decreases the performance again, so I was wondering if it is at all possible to just put a color color between background and object and blend the color with object only. Hope this clears the confusion a little and not adds to it..

Comment: Makes more sense now, but I still can't say I fully understand. Does the object you're drawing and 'first_layer' cover the exact same pixel area? Or were you hoping to just cover the screen with an 'invisible' first_layer, and then just see the color in the area where the fur is drawn, while seeing the background otherwise? If that's the case then I don't know if simple blending will get you the result you want.

Comment: Yes, exactly this >  hoping to just cover the screen with an 'invisible' first_layer, and then just see the color in the area where the fur is drawn, while seeing the background otherwise.. Well thank you. I guess I will have to figure some other way ) Good to know I should not spend more time on blending.. if you can post this as an answer, I will accept it..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the brief description, it sounds like you could blend layer 2 (sphere) onto layer 1 (first_layer), and then blit that atop layer 0 (background).  The first blend should be possible using the usual alpha blending parameters:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

However, `glBlendFunc` is quite outdated.  These days, OpenGL on both the desktop and mobile support shaders, which can much more easily achieve what you want.

Comment: BlendFunc is not outdated, it's still an essential part of the pipeline. Shaders don't yet have the ability to sample the destination framebuffer at the time of writing.

Comment: @Tim True, indeed - I was thinking of something else from the superseded part of the API.